# functions and variable scope within a m file

Tags: matlab

I have a single m file. The m file contains a rather large function that I wish to break down into my smaller manageable functions.

I have tried to breakdown the code into smaller functions that make logical sense. There are however some variables that need to be passed to every function. I was wondering if I should make these variables global? If so am I correct in saying that I need to do the following,

1) declare my variable as global in the main function of my m file.

```
  function my_main_function 

         global myvar

  end
```

2) also declare my variable as global in the sub function of the same m file?

```
  function my_sub_function

       global myvar

  end
```

Can you not just define the variable once as global in the m file? Seems bit of a pain otherwise? Or is there a better approach to sharing variables?

Comment: You can think about using nested functions for certain cases, where the only purpose of that helper function is to help its parent. Then, by seeing this structure, the purpose of that helper function will be very clear to any reader (instead of using many not-nested functions within one m file). More to read: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html especially http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-73993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a serious job about Matlab programming, you should learn Matlab object oriented programming.

http://www.mathworks.fr/company/newsletters/articles/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-in-matlab.html

From my experience, Matlab written software written function after function with global variables lead to spaghetti code.

Sit back, take the time to do your job correctly and enjoy the benefit of learning !

Comment: I have to agree with what you say about Matlab functions. I do not enjoy using MATLAB currently as it is hard to write decent code. Sadly though I need to complete this task in the next two days. I will learn how to use OO in MATLAB afterwards.